# Everything gets distorted when animating?

Tags: animation, transforms

When i made a new action called reload , it all looks fine and dandy ... and then i move the green line frame thing and[image: move it one bit] THIS happens ... I swear nothing works ... 
[image: Before moving green line]

Comment: Nope.(everything is X-ray )

Comment: so you want the .blend file? , oh by the way i have animated before but this never happened , it only happens when i make a new action

Comment: yup , if i understand what you said right , everything works absolutly perfect , i have a youtube video of a previous animation i made and nothing was wrong with that , http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAJF89jAmTc , different arms same rig - i think it has everything to do with the action

Comment: Yes, please upload some .blend file with this problem.

Comment: ok where should i upload it

Comment: [PasteAll](http://pasteall.org/blend/) will do.

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/25875 there

Answer (score 4):

The most frequent cause of this problem, in my experience, is multiple **Armature** modifier on the object. With that setup, the mesh deformed by the first **Armature** modifier gets further deformed by subsequent modifiers, which results in broken deformation.

[image: 1b]

Also check that the bones are keyframed using plain **Location** / **Rotation** / **Scale** keying set. Keyframing with **Visual Loc/Rot/Scale** can ruin certain constrained bone setup. (Just for more complete information. This is unlikely in your rig's case, being not constrained at all.)

**EDIT:** I've seen the file, and found the rig animatable as expected.

[image: 2a]

But I notice the hand object is scaled way down to fit the armature. That could be a problem, because it'd ruin the animation if the object's scale is somehow reset or keyframed to a different value. Maybe you've done something inadvertent when keyframing this particular action, that triggers the object scale's change. I suggest to **Apply** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale* the object and redo the animation data.

Comment: how do i check how many modifiers i have on my armature?

Comment: Check the mesh, not the armature. Actually what's contained in your .blend itself still doesn't provide any clue, so this answer relies on guesswork.

Comment: ok what i could do is give you the whole file if you want , see if that works since you know  whole lot more than me :) Oh and thanks for the help i really appreciate it !

Comment: Are . you . kidding . ME . I think i just solved the problem , i set the keyframe settings to LocRot AND scale , before , i only had it to LocRot

Comment: Well, that's unexpected. Glad it's solved :)

Comment: ill let you know if something goes wrong , i know somethings bund to happen ... Hey , thank you for your time , you really helped me learn a few things :D

Comment: mmm its not working again , the same thing happens , but when i enter the next keyframe

Comment: Please upload the full .blend file, mesh+rig+action, if you don't mind.

Comment: ok i will : http://pasteall.org/blend/25881

Comment: yea , the mesh was HUGE! , like 50 times the size of it right now , i had to scale it or it would be so hard ...